# VueJS router-link doesn't update component content

Tags: api, vue.js, vuex

> Category component

```
<ul v-else>
  <li
     v-for="cat in getCategories">
     <router-link :to="{ name: 'ProductsCategory', params: {category_name: cat.name}}">{{ cat.name }}</router-link>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This works fine and redirect fine to the correct link.

> Problem is

When it redirect it doesn't call again the state while i am using **vuex**.

> Component script

```
    computed: {
      getLoading () {
        return this.$store.state.companyInfo.loading;
      },
      getCompanyBasicInfo () {
        return this.$store.state.companyInfo.companyBasicInfo;
      },
      getCategories () {
        return this.$store.state.categories.categoriesName;
      },
      getCategoriesLoading () {
        return this.$store.state.categories.loadingState;
      },
      getCataegoryProducts () {
        return this.$store.state.products.getCategoryProducts;
      },
    },
    created() {
      this.$store.dispatch('getCategories', this.$route.params);
      this.$store.dispatch('getCategoryProductsAction', this.$route.params);
      this.$store.dispatch('getCompanyBasicInfo', this.$route.params);
    }
```

It should call `getCategoryProductsAction` which call my API and filter due  to the `router-link` params.

Answer (score 3):

This may be normal, because this component is not destroyed, but the `$route` parameters have changed.

So you can watch the `$route` for `params.category_name` changed

```
watch: {
  // when redirect to new category_name, this will be callback
  '$route': (new, old) => {
     if (new.params.category_name !== old.params.category_name) {
        // reload data, same with created()
     }
  }
}
```

see more: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/data-fetching.html#fetching-after-navigation

Comment: It should be `$route(new, old) {`

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use the watch lifecycle in Vue.js.

Basically what is does is watching your route and when it changes you can tell it to run a function.

example:

```
  watch: {
// call again the method if the route changes
        '$route': 'initService'
```

}